# How to optimize Grails build and test execution speed?

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, grails, testing, parallel-processing

What are the techniques to improve the time taken for a Grails project to build and run its unit tests? For example, does Grails have an equivalent to the [Maven 3 parallel build feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3)?

I am currently using Grails to build my application (not Gradle, etc), with [Spock tests](https://code.google.com/p/spock/), being driven by Jenkins. I found a script to [parallelize unit and integration tests](http://naleid.com/blog/2010/08/26/running-grails-unit-and-integration-tests-in-parallel/), but I'm looking for more.

Here are some related issues:

- [Integration and unit tests in large Grails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610557/integration-and-unit-tests-in-large-grails-project/5614397#5614397)
- [How to do concurrent modification testing for grails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162910/how-to-do-concurrent-modification-testing-for-grails-application/7865743)
- [How to speed up grails test execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942066/how-to-speed-up-grails-test-execution)

UPDATE:

- I'd like to answer some of my own question: check out the Grails [Partition Tests plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/partition-tests) (found link on [Grails Test Recipes](https://github.com/tomaslin/grails-test-recipes), which also looks like a great collection of information).

Comment: please add update as answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at plugin below for grails. This will allow execution of test cases into partitions which could be parallel as well.
https://github.com/adrianbk/grails-partition-tests

It example usage could be(same is shared in link as well)

```
grails test partition-test "--split=1" "--totalSplits=1" --verbose --echoOut --stacktrace
```

split specify which partition to run and totalSplits specifies the total number of Partitions.